# Вылетает nginx сервер при запросе на не существующие изображения

Tags: django, ubuntu, nginx

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]У меня есть сервер nginx на котором запущен backend на django. Я не очень разбираюсь в nginx, но в последнее время он начал вылетать. Открыв логи ошибок nginx я увидел только ошибки об не найденном изображении вроде этого. И таких ошибок много. Но разве nginx не должен пропускать такие ошибки и работать дальше в рабочем состоянии. Вылетает где то раз, два в сутки, без привязки к времени. Помогает от этого перезагрузка nginx. В чем может быть дело?

```
2021/04/03 00:28:14 [error] 60678#60678: *589 open() "/var/www/html/lk_sizze/media/images_elements/Frame_6619.png" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 188.247.187.250, server: lk.sizze.io, request: "GET /media/images_elements/Frame_6619.png HTTP/1.1", host: "lk.sizze.io", referrer: "http://localhost:3000/
```

Comment: Что значит "вылетает"? Как вы это определяете?

Comment: @andreymal Не верно высказался, он отключается. При команде nginx status показывает faild и мой backend не работает.

Comment: Написано killed. Он не вылетает а убит. Вопрос кем. Скорее всего OOM-киллером ядра. Значит у вас не хватает памяти или неверно настроены параметры для той что имеется. Ситуация банальная.

Comment: https://forum.nginx.org/read.php?2,290159,290161#msg-290161

Comment: Ошибка segv означает что он был убит за обращение к чужой памяти.  Одна из возможных причин по ссылке на форуме nginx